# select and deselect check box on basis of dynamic value.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list if classes and sections in input type check box.
All the values classes and ids are coming dynamically. how call i select and deselect all the check box like

If i select "Class One" all its sections get selected

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-lg-2">#</th>
<th class="col-lg-2">Classes</th>
<th class="col-lg-2">Sections</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-title="#">
1                                                            </td>
<td data-title="">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input onclick="checkallsection(this.id)" id="One" type="checkbox" value="">One                                                                </label>
</td>
<td data-title="">


<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="One" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="1">A</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="One" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="2">B</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-title="#">
2                                                            
</td>
<td data-title="">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input onclick="checkallsection(this.id)" id="Two" type="checkbox" value="">Two                                                                
</label>
</td>
<td data-title="">


<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="5">A</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="6">B</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="7">C</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-title="#">
3                                                            
</td>
<td data-title="">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input onclick="checkallsection(this.id)" id="Three" type="checkbox" value="">Three                                                                
</label>
</td>
<td data-title="">


<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Three" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="8">A</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-title="#">
4                                                            
</td>
<td data-title="">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input onclick="checkallsection(this.id)" id="Four" type="checkbox" value="">Four                                                                
</label>
</td>
<td data-title="">


<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Four" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="9">A</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-title="#">
5                                                            
</td>
<td data-title="">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input onclick="checkallsection(this.id)" id="Five" type="checkbox" value="">Five                                                                
</label>
</td>
<td data-title="">


<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Five" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="10">A</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Five" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="11">B</label>
</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which checkboxes you want to `select` and which `deselect`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: [See Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu85g8rL/9/)

HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-lg-2">#</th>
            <th class="col-lg-2">Classes</th>
            <th class="col-lg-2">Sections</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="#">
                1                                                            
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="cls" id="One" type="checkbox" value="">One                                                                </label>
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="One" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="1">A</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="One" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="2">B</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="#">
                2                                                            
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="cls" id="Two" type="checkbox" value="">Two                                                                
                </label>
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="5">A</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="6">B</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Two" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="7">C</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="#">
                3                                                            
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="cls" id="Three" type="checkbox" value="">Three                                                                
                </label>
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Three" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="8">A</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="#">
                4                                                            
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="cls" id="Four" type="checkbox" value="">Four                                                                
                </label>
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Four" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="9">A</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="#">
                5    
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="cls" id="Five" type="checkbox" value="">Five                                                                
                </label>
            </td>
            <td data-title="">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Five" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="10">A</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="Five" type="checkbox" name="secid[]" value="11">B</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cls', function() {    

if($(this).parents('td').next("td").find('input').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents('td').next("td").find('input').prop('checked', false);
} else {  
   $(this).parents('td').next("td").find('input').prop('checked', true);
}

});
```

Comment: If it works you should Accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you.